# Configure minimum of successes in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

i am using jmeter non-gui mode (run from cmd) .
and i am trying to do 2 things.

1. getting whole answer if run passed/fail (not by checking the errors
   percent)
2. can i configure minimum of tests that have to pass and then it will
   mark the run as PASS?

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter doesn't do any checks, if you want to conditionally automatically fail the test basing on the errors threshold consider the following options:

1. Using [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) tool as a wrapper, it provides [Pass/Fail Criteria subsystem](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) allowing setting acceptable error levels
2. Using [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) which provides `jmeter-check-results` goal

In both cases you will have non-zero [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) in case of errors which will act as the indicator of the test failures